# Magento 2.1 custom theme (Login and Registration Form)

Tags: layout, magento-2.1, luma-theme

I have successfully created Magento using/ inherited from Blank default theme. When I remove the default css

```
<remove src="css/styles-m.css" />
<remove src="css/styles-l.css" />
```

I see the login and registration form appears on the home page. How do I remove them using referenceBlock. Also, if I remove them will these be available via http://www...com/customer/account/login/

Comment: No It is not so. I just checked http://www...com/contact/ page. Also, I saw the form has been added as pop-up. However, no popup appeared when I reverted to original settings (reinstalled it too).